# how to connect pressure gauge to fuel line

Tags: fuel-system, tools, measurement, fuel-pressure

2009 toyota corolla 1.8L

How can I find connectors to tee in a pressure gauge to my fuel line?

The fuel lines are pipes so it's not possible to cut one to tee in.

Below are instructions from the service manual.

A google search on part numbers in bold, 09268-31012 and 09268-45014, show these are gauge sets that cost about $450 and up.

How can I find connectors that will work with my fuel lines without spending a fortune ?

[image: service manual pressure gauge instructions]

Comment: I made several - a bolt and a couple of suitable nuts, drill and solder... made several for oil pressure gauges back in the day.

Comment: i bought https://www.amazon.com/BETOOLL-Fuel-Pressure-0-100PSI-Fittings/dp/B07LF26ZTJ and https://www.amazon.com/Lisle-39210-Main-Fuel-Disconnect/dp/B002MCTVH2 hope they work

Comment: To the closer-voters: this is really about the tools useful for diagnosis, not so much about  shopping for them. I think it's on-topic.

Comment: Not really a problem to use a tubing cutter to cut a metal line anywhere you want. You will need a flaring tool or good compression fittings to connect a "T" for  a tube to the gage.

Comment: two more links that may help others, this video illustrates separating a toyota fuel line https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fC6gK9x8p8k and this photo shows coupling someone constructed for a pressure gauge, viewing this photo lead me to guess the pressure gauge i linked above may work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fC6gK9x8p8k